# Get indexes of 2 duplicated elements in 2d array of INTs JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I need some help from the experts. I've got a task to find 2 duplicate elements in a 2d array and print out their indexes. Here's the code i've made. It creates a 2d array, then fill it manually from the keyboard. But now i have some problems with the method that finds and prints the duplicates. It prints FALSE if there are no duplicates, and TRUE if there are some. But I can't make it print out ALL the duplicates and its indexes. Please help me with this. Best regards

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        out.println("Введите размерность массива n:");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        out.println("Введите размерность массива m:");

        int m = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        int [][] a = new int [n][m];

        out.println("Введите числа массива :");

        int i,j;

        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            }
        }
        out.println("Введенный массив : ");
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++, out.println()) {
            for (j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                out.printf(" %4d", a[i][j]);
            }
        }

        out.println(extra(a));

    }

    private static boolean extra(int[][] data) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                if (set.contains(data[i][j])) {

                    out.printf("[%d][%d] - %d\n", i, j, data[i][j]);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    set.add(data[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Your `return true` returns as soon as the first duplicate is found. How do you think this affects your ability to find all duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your method and used one boolean variable found..This will work

```
private static boolean extra(int[][] data) {
    boolean found = false;
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            if (set.contains(data[i][j])) {

                out.printf("[%d][%d] - %d\n", i, j, data[i][j]);
                found = true;
            } else {
                set.add(data[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: hmm.. sometimes we need to give fish but sometimes we also need to give the fishing pole.. perhaps, have you seen @Jason's answer?

Answer (score 1):

A general method for determining if any item in a collection satisfies a condition, while also processing every item, is:

```
boolean conditionSatisfied = false;

for each item in collection {
    if item satisfies condition {
        process item;
        conditionSatisfied = true;
    }
}

return conditionSatisfied;
```